# How to manually override property OnLoad method in NHibernate?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, listener

Is it possible to manually change an entity when it's loaded from the database by NHibernate. Is there an `OnLoad` event listener which we can override or inherit from which will allow us to manually set an entity.

For clarity, we wish to assign a custom entity when the property is `null`. We are successfully doing the opposite when we persist to the database however would rather implement the logic in an NHibernate listener rather than in the property "Getter".

Please note we do not want to use `IInterceptors` as we are using the latest version of NHibernate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement `IPostLoadEventListener`. It's just one method:

```
void OnPostLoad(PostLoadEvent @event)
```

Which I think is exactly what you want.

Comment: Is NHibernate smart enough to know that a custom entity is being substituted for NULL, therefore not flagging the property as "Dirty".

Comment: Thanks Diego. With your answer and the page below I managed to find a solution. http://nhforge.org/wikis/howtonh/prefent-nhibernate-from-saving-default-relations.aspx